# Asynchronous command execution in Nightwatch JS

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

When I run the following code ...

```
console.log("0001")
browser.pause(5000, function() {
    console.log("0002")
})
console.log("0003")
```

... the output is 0001, 0003, 0002. How can I get the commands to run sequentially so that the output is 0001, 0002, 0003?

Comment: hi perhaps run the third command from within the callback of the second command?

Comment: Thanks.  I'm aware that I could move the console.log("0003") inside the callback immediately following console.log("0002").  Are there other solutions?

Comment: `await browser.pause()` might be another option https://webdriver.io/docs/sync-vs-async.html

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.  This worked ..

```
'Test Commmand Queue': async function (browser) {

    console.log("0001")
    await browser.pause(5000, function() {
        console.log("0002")
    })
    console.log("0003")

}
```

Output 0001, 0002, 0003